# overload the bracket operator with multiple parameters

Tags: python-2.7

I have built a wrapper around numpy array for simplification purposes I will display only the necessary part to show the error:

```
class Matrix(object):
    """wrap around numpy array
    """

    def __init__(self, shape, fill_value):
        self.matrix = np.full(shape, fill_value)

    def __getitem__(self, a, b):
        return self.matrix[a, b]



m = Matrix((10, 10), 5)
print(m[5, 5])
```

the print statement generates the following error:

```
KeyError: __getitem__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

what's the fix to access m using the [] operator like the follwing:

```
m[1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have a class `Matrix` with an attribute `matrix` which is a numpy array. Therefore you would need to reference the attribute first and then pass the indices:

```
>>> m.matrix[5,5]
5
```

At this point, you have **not** wrapped around a numpy array. Depending on what you want to do, this could be a step in the right direction:

```
class Matrix(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, shape, fill_value=0):
        return np.full(shape, fill_value)

>>> m = MyMatrix((10, 10), 5)
>>> print(m[5, 5])
>>> 5
```

However, this essentially does nothing more than `m = np.full(shape, fill_value)`. I suppose you are going to want to add custom attributes and methods to a numpy array, in which you should check out [this example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html#simple-example-adding-an-extra-attribute-to-ndarray) in the numpy documentation.

Answer (score 2):

the solution is to pass a tuple inside a variable like the following:

```
class Matrix(object):
    """wrap around numpy array
    """

    def __init__(self, shape, fill_value):
        self.matrix = np.full(shape, fill_value)

    def __getitem__(self, a):
        # we could do also do return self.matrix[a[0], a[1]]
        return self.matrix[a] 


    m = Matrix((10, 10), 5)
    print(m[5, 5])
```